# How to remount USB device by VID:PID?

Tags: bash, usb, mount

I sometimes find that my SanDisk USB stick has failed to mount.  I'd like to script in a remount for just this device that is NOT mounted with `/etc/fstab`.  How can I identify the stick(s) and then remount them without knowing any kind of `UUID` or fdisk identifier ahead of time?

I'd like to:

```
sudo remount --all
```

just my devices with VID `0781`, for example:

```
$ lsusb | grep 0781
Bus 001 Device 047: ID 0781:5583 SanDisk Corp.
```

without knowing the `/dev/sd*` filepath.

Perhaps phrased another way, is `sudo remount --all` safe to do if I'm also using one of the devices outlined in `/etc/fstab`?